# how do I use a database for my application

Tags: database, glassfish

I dont have a database software on my laptop. But am building an web application using Java with Glassfish server. Now where do I store data. and how do i see the databases,tables? Should i download a DBMS package or glassfish server is enough?

Comment: GlassFish includes a database. You just have to know how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish comes bundled with [**Java DB** (Derby)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html). Start it with [**"asadmin start-database"**](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/quick-start-guide.pdf).

(You do not have to manually create tables and such with [`Java EE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition), [`JPA`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html) will do that for you.)